# ASP.NET Binding two textbox controls for time display/edit

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DetailsView control that is bound to a single table in my database.
one of the fields in the DB is a `DATETIME` field which represents the TIME of something (i'm not using the date...)

I want two textboxes in my template field that will bound to this time data,  one for Hours and second for Minutes.

What is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first TextBox for hours(24h format):

```
Text='<%# Eval("DateTimeField", "{0:HH}") %>'
```

second TextBox for minutes:

```
Text='<%# Eval("DateTimeField", "{0:mm}") %>'
```

[Custom DateTime Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks! will it work with Bind instead of Eval? (i want it to be editable)

Comment: @user1666969: Yes, formatting works similar for `Bind` and `Eval`.

Comment: Hi, when i replace it in BIND it gives me error:  String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: i mean that if i put what u said first: <%# Eval("DateTimeField", "{0:mm}") %> it works (without updating/inserting ofcourse).  but if i put Bind("DateTimeField", "{0:mm}") it raises exception when updating/inserting:    String was not recognized as a valid DateTime